# Flutter: Can't run

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

```
C:\ProjectFlutter\myapp>flutter run
Using hardware rendering with device Android SDK built for x86. If you get graphics artifacts, consider enabling
software rendering with "--enable-software-rendering".
Launching lib\main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...
Initializing gradle...                                              2.6s
Resolving dependencies...                                           6.2s

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
```

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':app:transformNativeLibsWithMergeJniLibsForDebug'.

  > Internal error when trying to read zip file 'C:\flutter\bin\cache\artifacts\engine\android-arm\flutter.jar'.
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 26s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'... Done                        27.7s
Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

Comment: Try doing `flutter clean` then try running it again.

Answer (score 0):

Try `flutter clean` then run the app again. 
I faced the same issue today and then tried this command which worked for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your android/build.gradle file looks something like this:

```
buildscript {
    //
    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure this line is present ```maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }```